# How would I use a CURSOR to iterate through a list of values to do a calculation for each value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I have searched and searched for a way to do what I'm trying to do, but I haven't found a solution yet. I have dates stored in a table like so:

```
Dates      Code    Sum
1-15-2015  AAA     (to be calculated)
2-2-2016   BBB     (to be calculated)
11-23-2015 CCC     (to be calculated)
```

The `sum` for each record in the table is calculated based on the date in the `Date` column. I want to use the date from the `Date` column as a parameter of sorts to do the calculation for each record in the table. I assume a CURSOR would be the best approach, but I am new to SQL and I don't how to implement such functionality. For example's sake, you can totally make up the sum calculation. It's trivial, anyway. I have looked at several examples elsewhere, but I've had no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**The Sum Calculation**

The sum is calculated by pulling values out of another database, via a pass-through query, within a date range. The date range is determined by the date in the `Dates` column of the example table. The date range is the date value in the `Dates` column to today's date (`GetDate()`). All I need to know how to do is change the left date to the date in the `Dates` column for each record in the sample table. Efficiency is key.

Comment: You don't need a cursor, you should use a `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` for the `Sum` column.  What is your logic for the `Sum` column?

Comment: @Siyual It's just a basic `Sum(StuffToSum)` aggregate function. You could totally make it up if that helps you create some sample code.

Comment: Don't ever assume that a CURSOR would be the best approach, because it is almost 100% **never** the best approach. It's usually the **worst** approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's not clear to me, exactly what it is you don't know how to do.

Comment: @TomH Honestly, I don't want to have to use a cursor. I'm just so used to thinking in terms of procedural code that I can't wrap my mind around a set-based approach.

Comment: Please explain the calculation, it could be as simple as a SUM.... GROUP BY Dates or more complicated but we have no way of knowing.

Comment: @SteveFord I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will be very generic, but you'll need to do either an `OUTER APPLY` or a `CROSS APPLY` depending on if you want to filter `NULL` values or not.

The syntax would look something similar to this:

```
Select  A.Dates, A.Code, X.Sum
From    YourTable   A
Outer Apply
(
    Select  Sum(B.StuffToSum)   As  Sum
    From    OtherDatabase.OtherSchema.OtherTable    B
    Where   B.Date Between A.Dates And GetDate()
) X
```

Your `OUTER APPLY` logic should match the actual logic you're using, I'm just using this as an example showing how you can get a date range from the Date in the first table to `GETDATE()`.

Using an `OUTER APPLY`, if there are no values in your other table that fall in that date range, it will return `NULL`.  In the case of a `CROSS APPLY`, the entire record will be filtered out (this behaviour is similar to that of `INNER` and `OUTER JOINS`).